# Oracle SQL Import IDs From Text File

Tags: sql, oracle, text-files

I am looking at doing a clash for our billing database with our sales database to make sure all accounts are in sync (Registered On Both Sides, Lost On Both sides etc)

I have exported the IDs of the Files from the sales database onto a textfile on the network.

I now want to import that file of ids so that my query does the following

SELECT * FROM ACCOUNT WHERE ACCOUNT ID IN(Read In From Textfile On Server)

Is this possible to do?

Comment: [Read about external tables](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SUTIL/GUID-44323E01-7D72-45EC-915A-99E596769D9E.htm#SUTIL011). The files needs to be somewhere the Oracle account can read it though, via a directory object. How did you 'export' it?

Comment: Hi Alex, Ive exported it via to a csv file (From Salesforce). Ive then put quotes on the open and close of each account ID (In and around 75,000). Now I just need to be able to read it in to my query on SQL Developer